# WP-API : post_meta not updated... but have another entry

Tags: post-meta, wp-api

When creating a post, I put some post_meta

here is the code for the creation edition and deletion of a post
https://gist.github.com/eduplessis/dc530523f0b98ae233dc

and here is the result of the post_meta when it's created

```
Array(

[time_client_email] => Array
(
    [0] => email@client..com
)

[time_client_website] => Array
(
    [0] => clientwebsite.com
)
)
```

When I update it here is the result

```
Array(
[time_client_email] => Array
(
    [0] => email@client..com
    [1] => email@client..com
)

[time_client_website] => Array
(
    [0] => clientwebsite.com
    [1] => clientwebsite.com
)
)
```

My question is :

is it because of the revision....

or something is wrong....

because I think the desirable result would be ... if exist and the same value "do nothing" .... if exist and not the same value "replace"

here's a link to the issue on github. https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1339

Comment: I've answered my question... when your not giving the id of the post meta ... it's creating another one ... you give the id and it's updating...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've answered my question... when your not giving the id of the post meta ... it's creating another one ... you give the id and it's updating... –